# Why many to one with backlink not allowed in objectbox-dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

I have this structure:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Media {
  @Id(assignable: true)
  int id = 0;
  int lid = 0;
  String url = '';
  String? title;
}

@Entity()
class NewsPicture extends Media {
  @override
  @Id(assignable: true)
  int id = 0;

  @Backlink('newsPicture')
  final news = ToOne<News>();
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
@Entity()
class News extends Data<News> implements DataInterface<News> {
  @Id(assignable: true)
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 0)
  int lid = 0;
  final Picture = ToMany<NewsPicture>();
}
```

and at the generation process, the objectbox_generator:resolver gives me this error message:

> invalid use of @Backlink() annotation - may only be used on a ToMany<>
> field

Why is it not allowed? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported in that direction because it's not really needed (doesn't help with anything), you can just flip the direction/change the place where the relation is stored. Also, `ToOne` relations are more efficient to store, because they're just a single field in a database, while a standalone `ToMany` relations require an intermediate "mapping table".

If you update your model like this, it's going to work and you won't see a difference in the way how you can work with it in your app:

```dart
@Entity()
class NewsPicture extends Media {
  @override
  @Id(assignable: true)
  int id = 0;

  final news = ToOne<News>();
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
@Entity()
class News extends Data<News> implements DataInterface<News> {
  @Id(assignable: true)
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 0)
  int lid = 0;

  @Backlink()
  final Picture = ToMany<NewsPicture>();
}
```